# Visual Studio 2015 add Bower configuration file bug

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, bower

See the following image:

[image]

After creating an *empty* **ASP.NET MVC 5** project in **Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3**, I'm trying to add the *Bower Configuration File*. Note that the dialog says:

> Bower Configuration Files for: Bower.json and .bowerrc.

But as you can see in the Solution Explorer, the `.bowerrc` is not added. Is this supposed to happen? Or do you need to add this manually?

I'm trying to follow [this blog](http://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/converting-your-asp-net-mvc5-application-to-use-bower-grunt-and-gulp/) on converting an MVC 5 app to use Bower.

*Nodejs, npm and Bower are installed (all latest version as of writing).*

Comment: Just had the same bug, found anything?

Comment: @Euphoria unfortunately, no. I've sent feedback to Microsoft about this issue, but I don't think the priority of a bug on this scale will be high for them.

Comment: Fair dues, by default the bower packages get put inside a folder called bower_components for me which isn't ideal but works. Could always have a grunt task of copying the contents to a 'custom lib' folder and delete the bower_components.

Comment: You can always manually add the bower config file. But it just strikes me weird that the dialog window description says it will add both the bower json and config file..